# Measure websocket latency from c# client

Tags: c#, .net, websocket

I am trying to figure out a good strategy to measure latency with the .net `ClientWebSocket` class, knowing I don't have access to the server code. The client is an application, not a web page.

I am surprised that there isn't a built-in function to achieve this. I see that the code internally handles ping and pongs already, but it seems I cannot intercept a pong myself.

however, I am new to this interface so I am likely missing something (but couldn't find an answer googling it). Please help.

Edit: I assume that the .net WebSocket class implements the RFC standard and I know that internally it handles the ping/pong frames.
I also know that my server implements the RFC standard and can respond to a Ping with a Pong.

Comment: To measure latency you need to know when the *server* started a call. `surprised that there isn't a built-in function to achieve this` that would require cooperation from the server. A standard's based way is to use OpenTelemetry for distributed tracing.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos but I thought that the ping/pong messages were standard. maybe that was a wrong assumption, wasn't it? Edit: it looks to me that the ping frame is part of the RFC standard https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6455#section-5.5.2

Comment: That's not what most people would mean by `latency` in a networking context. Besides, if you refer [to this code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/a1468ed70bc03626c31af5e0b0630ef98000c78f/src/libraries/System.Net.WebSockets/src/System/Net/WebSockets/ManagedWebSocket.cs#L546) it's only used to keep the connection alive. It sends a *pong* message and the response is ignored

Comment: sending a ping and measuring how long it takes to receive a pong is good enough for me as latency measurement. This was already working fine with the websocket implementation I was using before switching to the net one. At this point, I suspect I just need to find a third library.